# Is there a way to easily locate my base?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

In Brilliant Diamond, I created my secret base in the underground and placed a few statues. Due to the holidays, I took a few days off from playing. When I entered back into the underground, I was placed in a different part of the map and could not remember where I placed my base nor could I find it on the map.

Is there a way I can easily find and travel to my base so that I can place additional statues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open full map of Grand Underground, and look for red dot.

Full map can be accessed by hitting **Y** button:
[image: accessing full map]

On full map there are various markers:

- Glowing red dot with red circle around, that moves together with you, is your location
- Small dark red dot is your base
- Orange dots are mining spots
- Blue dots, which tend to move, are other players

[image: full map]

All markers are also visible on mini-map, which can be changed from local to full view by clicking **right stick**, but hunting for one red pixel in colorful mosaic does not sound very easy.

If you want to go to another section of underground you must return to Overworld (*Go up* in **Y** menu) and dig down from another place.

Here's a handy list of spots from which you can reach different sections:

- Largest section is almost everywhere, eg. Hearthome town
- Central section: Celestic town
- North-west section: Snowpoint town
- North-east section: Fight area (post game content)
- South-east section: Beach between Pastoria (fly there, walk east) and Sunyshore towns. Narrow piece of shore allows you to reach that section without surfing to islands south of beach.
- South-west section: Sandgem town (starting area)

[image: digging zone map]

Comment: That's good information, thanks for that! Since the underground is divided into multiple unconnected sections, is there a way I can move between them to access my base if I'm in a different section?

Comment: @Wondercricket ya gotta return to overworld and dig in another place. I added a map with spots I am using.